# simple_html_dom.php - получить содержимое атрибута

Tags: php

Как с помощью библиотеки simple_html_dom.php получить содержимое атрибута?

```
<td class="download">    
<a href = "data-default="Здесь содержимое кода"> </a> 
</td>
```

Добрался до ячейки. Там много мусора всякого. Нужно именно с **data-default** вытащить содержимое. Всю голову сломал уже. Регулярки не советовать.

Comment: пока что у вас какой-то не валидный кусок разметки. что за `href = "data-default="`

Answer (score 4):

Если предположить что исходные данные выглядят так:

```
$txt = <<<HTML
  <html>
    <body>
       <td class="download">
          <a href="#" data-default="Здесь содержимое кода"></a>.
       </td>
    </body>
  </html>
HTML;
```

то получение значения атрибута `data-download` первой ссылки внутри класса `.download` выглядит следующим образом:

```
$html = str_get_html($txt);
echo  $html->find(".download a",0)->{"data-default"};
```

Согласно [примерам документации](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) атрибуты получаются просто как свойство объектов (например, `$a->href`), но в данном случае (вероятно в этом ваша проблема и заключалась?) именование атрибута содержит дефис. Такие случаи могут достаточно часто случаться, например, при десериализации данных и т.п. опять же согласно [документации](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex), доступ к ним осуществляется с помощью фигурных скобок

Comment: Все верно сделано, за исключением - Кавычки одинарные. С двойными не работал код {'data-default'}

Comment: @LEX без разницы должно быть двойные или нет. код вставлен рабочий, проверенный.